# Is it safe to delete huge Windows "DeliveryOptimization" files?

Tags: windows-10, cache

I am running out of space on my D: drive and I noticed that there are two files that contains 180gb together, inside of D:\DeliveryOptimization\Cache.

[image: Path and file sizes]

Is it safe to delete them? If yes, should I just Shift+Del them or do it on a specific way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These files are there if you somehow enabled the feature to download for other computers.

If you are not servicing other computers, you can delete these files.

Use Disk Cleanup to delete the files

[Clear Delivery files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/clear-the-delivery-optimization-cache-c0e93802-5800-5554-7380-594014a6089b#:%7E:text=Delivery%20Optimization%20in%20Windows%2010,the%20taskbar%2C%20enter%20disk%20cleanup.)

> Delivery Optimization in Windows 10 clears its cache automatically.
> Files are removed from the cache after a short time period or when
> their contents take up too much disk space. However, If you need more
> disk space on your PC, you can clear the cache manually.
>
> In the search box on the taskbar, enter disk cleanup. Choose the Disk
> Cleanup app from the list of results.
>
> On the Disk Cleanup tab, select the Delivery Optimization Files check
> box.
>
> Select OK. On the dialog that appears, choose Delete Files.

If something has gone awry, you can try deleting manually.

Comment: I alredy cleared it using disk cleanup, but only 8gb were deleted, and the 180gb files are still there.

Comment: Per the article, the rest should go soon.  If not, something has gone awry and you ca try deleting manually